# Using an Animator State as a Switch with no Animation

Tags: unity, animator, animation-states

I have the attached portion of a sub-state machine in my animator. The parent layer is connected to the states "Standing" and "Prone Idle" using transitions with conditions "isStanding == true" and "isStanding == false" respectively. Things work fine.

I, however, do not like the multiple transitions invading the sub-state machine, and I want to enter the sub-state machine at "Entry" and leave it at "Exit". So I thought maybe I can add a state "Stance Switch" that will forward the condition variable "isStanding" to both "Standing" and "Prone Idle". This works in the sense that it allows me to get rid of the invading transitions, but the animated object will briefly go to T-Pose when the animator is playing "Stance Switch" because there is no animation attached to it.

I do not want the state "Stance Switch" to play any animation or make the animated object go to T-Pose. Is this possible? Is there something I can do to make the state a pure Switch that changes nothing about the animated object's animation?

Cheers.
[image]